# В мобильной версии сайта модальное окно Bootstrap 4 не отображается

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

[image: Смартфон]При тестировании в браузере всё корректно, но на самом телефоне, появляется серый фон, но само окно не отображается, как исправить?

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
          <?=$_GET['title']?>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div>
                <center>
                  <h1>Оформите заявку</h1>
                </center>
                <div class="tab" role="tabpanel">
                  <!-- Tab panes -->
                  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="success.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($title) ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($year) ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="spec" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($spec) ?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">Имя</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="phone">Телефон</label>
                      <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Заказать</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, кому-то поможет, убрал в class="modal fade" класс fade, и всё заработало